# Move tag elements using CSS (without JS)

Tags: css, css-grid

I have this output:

```
H1

H2

P
```

But I want to to move H1 between H2 and P so the new output is:

```
H2

H1

P
```

Can this be done with CSS grid or any type of CSS?

Code (Changing HTML structure is not possible):

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>H1</h1>
  <div class="details">
    <h2>H2</h2>
    <p>P</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not without changing the HTML structure or using `display:contents`.

Comment: @Paulie_D Changing the HTML is not possible, can you help me with the CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`display:contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to "unwrap" the inner div..and the use flexbox and `order`.

CSS-Grid options also exist but also require `display:contents`.

```css
.details {
  display: contents;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h2 {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>H1</h1>
  <div class="details">
    <h2>H2</h2>
    <p>P</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was not even aware with display: contents yet, feeling foolish, but thanks to you, it's magical.